# How do I add components in the activity_main.xml?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to add a simple textview in the activity_main.xml but it won't let me add it to a custom location (As in drag and drop from the palette). Instead, it just gives me these green dotted boxes like in the picture below:

[image: Screenshot]

How do i fix this?

Comment: put it in content_main.xml

Comment: What do you mean by "a custom location"? What is the parent layout?

Comment: I wanted to say drag and drop basically.

Comment: You are not on XCode. On AndroidStudio, you have to edit the XML if you want to place you textview exactly where you want.

Comment: @Imbru that is not true. He is using the new constraint layout editor

Comment: @Tim Castelijns: Where can I change the layout from?

Comment: By clicking on it. If you don't know this kind of stuff, you ought to start doing some tutorials

Comment: I am actually. lol. just geting errors in my very first program.
And, what i meant about the layout was, where can I find the layout option. I found it in the palette but it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to add a textview to `activity_main.xml`, not in the `content_main.xml`.
Also if you want you can simply do it by text, with the `TextView` tag. Then you add the text in the `android:text="text you want"`.
If you want a custom location, you should use a Linear Layout or a Relative Layout and simply add padding or margin, the way you want to do it.

If you still want to use drag and drop you can, but make sure you do it in the right xml file, in this case, the `activity_main.xml` .

You can read more about the textview attributes here : [Textview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via the text editor.

Click the Text button at the bottom left of your screen and there try adding the next xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="protocols.doubleverify.com.protocols.main.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</LinearLayout>
```

- `android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"` specifying the the distance from left side of the screen, or x location.
- `android:layout_marginTop="40dp"` specifying the the distance from the top of the screen, or y location.

Comment: You can set the same margins without touching the raw XML file

Comment: @TimCastelijns From what I understood, he is trying to place the text-box in costume location aka specific x,y coordinates. What do you mean by wrong layout?

Comment: Just look at the picture.. he should be editing content_main.xml

Comment: @Tim this template is a bit complicated for somebody new. You need to understand what is the difference between activity_main and content_main. So I just suggested something simpler. OP question is just about some simple layouting in costume location. The fact that Android layouting is not designed this way is a different story.

Comment: You should explain why you suggested this "solution" to OP, not to me. Also if you want to keep it simple, I suggest you just use a LinearLayout instead of a FrameLayout